# OpenOffice Basic: how to show Unicode characters in a MsgBox correctly?

Tags: unicode, openoffice-calc, openoffice-basic

I've got a problem with one of my macros. I'm showing a string with Unicode characters in a msgbox.

```
MsgBox "ščř"
```

But all I get in the message box are ???s - until I open the BASIC IDE. Once I open the IDE, the message box starts showing the Unicode chars correctly, until I restart LibreOffice.

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: What is your operating system and version of LibreOffice?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this on my system (LO 5.0.3.2 on Win 10):

[image: MsgBox scr]

I assume this is what you intended, for Unicode characters `U+0161 U+010D U+0159`.  It rendered it this way immediately on loading LibreOffice.  I tried it with AOO 4.1.2 and it did not seem to have any problems either.

So it seems to be a problem specific to your system.  Fixing it might require digging through the control panel fonts and regional settings and perhaps reinstalling fonts or even LibreOffice.

Instead of using `MsgBox`, it may work better to [create a custom dialog](https://help.libreoffice.org/Basic/Creating_a_Basic_Dialog).  That would allow you to specify which font should be used, rather than leaving it up to the system to guess.